# CGPoint in GameDevelopment and SKScene?

Tags: swift

I'm positioning my nodes in the scene, but I'm finding it hard to understand why size.width can be used as an x value for CGPoint or size.height can be used for the y Value.

For example

```
let kShipSize = CGSize(width: 30, height 16)

    func setupShip () { 
        ship.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2 , y: kShipSize.height/2) 
}
```

what is `size.height` and why is it used for x and y coordinates in swift

Comment: I wouldn't say "it is used for x and y coordinates in Swift". It just so happens to be used to perform the calculations in the code you posted. The width and height can be used anywhere it makes sense in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`size.height` or `size.width` are Double/Int numbers which indicate how big the view is. Because they are numbers they can be used as an x/y coordinate.
They are **not** the frame, which I guess you are mistaking them with :)